# PHP Mail/ validate script does not work

Tags: php, email, validation, mailer

The following form gives the message "thank you for subscribing to the newsletter" if a correct email address is entered but it does not send the results to the designated `$to` address. Also If the email is invalid the 'please enter a valid email' message does not show. Could someone please help a php noob with these errors? Thanks

```
<?php
$email   = $_POST['email'];
$to      = "reb3qb13b@gmail.com";
$subject = "ADD THIS EMAIL ADDRESS TO THE MAILING LIST";
$body    = "\n\n";
$url     = 'http://10.0.1.3/~143b1';

if (! filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
    echo '<script> alert("PLEASE ENTER A VALID EMAIL ADDRESS") </script>';
    echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL='.$url.'">';
}
else
{
    if (mail($to, $subject, $body)) 
    {
        echo '<script> alert("THANK YOU FOR SUBSCRIBING TO THE NEWSLETTER") </script>';
        echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL='.$url.'">';
    } 
    else 
    {
        echo '<script> alert("THERE WAS AN UNEXPECTED ERROR. PLEASE TRY AGAIN LATER") </script>';
        echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL='.$url.'">';
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Excerpt from [mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) manual page:

> Returns TRUE if the mail was successfully **accepted for delivery**, FALSE otherwise.
>
> It is important to note that just because the mail was accepted for delivery, **it does NOT mean the mail will actually reach the intended destination**.

So I suppose your code is fine but there is a problem with your mail server.

Answer (score 0):

Are you developing on a local server? Is sendmail or some kind of SMTP service installed?

You also haven't listed a script type for your script tags which might cause some browsers not to execute the Javascript. What actually gets echoed to the page when you run the PHP? That should give you an indication of where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the code before body close tag, The DOM should be loaded first to execute your js code
Or try

```
if(1==1){
    echo "<script>alert('Test');</script>";
}
```

If alert is not working the problem is the position of your code